# Tensorflow 2.1 Dataset From Generator - ValueError: Error when checking input: expected Geo to have shape (504,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm having trouble getting my model to compile, I seem to be having this issue quite a lot and the error output isn't particularly useful:

> expected Geo to have shape (504,) but got array with shape (1,)

I understand that the shape has mismatched somewhere, but this error is not pointing me to any particular point in the code. Is it from the Input() layer, the first Dense layer or from the Generator itself?

My model is a multi input single output model, it takes a numpy array of 504 float inputs in the 'Geo' input and an SDF of 64,64,64,1 in the 'SDF' input. These get concatenated to output a 12 float result.

My logic follows:

```
# The Data Generator
# Input shape is 42, 12, 1
# SDF shape is 64, 64, 64

def data_generator(train_path, test_path):
    """
    Generator for loading geo data.
    """

    imgListTestSDF = test_path.parent
    imgListTestSDF = imgListTestSDF / "test_sdf"    

    imgListTrain = sorted(train_path.iterdir() )
    imgListTest = sorted(test_path.iterdir() )
    imgListTestSDF = sorted(imgListTestSDF.iterdir() )

    for dist, norm, norm_sdf in zip(imgListTrain, imgListTest, imgListTestSDF):
        norm = np.load(norm)['array']
        norm_sdf = np.load(norm_sdf)['array']
        dist = np.load(dist)['array']

        outshape = norm.shape[0] * 3 * 12
        print ("Out shape: %s" % (outshape,)) # Out shape: 504
        #norm = np.reshape(norm, (504))
        norm = norm.flatten()
        print ("Norm reshaped: %s" % (norm.shape,)) # Norm reshaped: (504,)

        norm_sdf = np.reshape(norm_sdf, IN_SDF_SHAPE)

        # Cast to float32, loaded as float64
        norm = norm.astype(np.float32)
        dist = dist.astype(np.float32)

        norm_combined = {}
        norm_combined['Geo'] = norm
        norm_combined['SDF'] = norm_sdf

        yield norm_combined, dist
```

NN Logic:

```
EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 10

IN_GEO_SHAPE = [504]
inGeoTensorShape = tf.TensorShape(IN_GEO_SHAPE)

IN_SDF_SHAPE = [64, 64, 64, 1]
inSDFTensorShape = tf.TensorShape(IN_SDF_SHAPE)

outTypes = ({'Geo': tf.dtypes.float32 , 'SDF' : tf.dtypes.float32}, tf.dtypes.float32)
outTensorShape = ({'Geo': inGeoTensorShape , 'SDF' : inSDFTensorShape }, tf.TensorShape([12,]))

trainGen = partial(data_generator, train, test) 
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(trainGen, outTypes, output_shapes=outTensorShape )


# Geo Dense layers.
inGeo = tf.keras.Input(shape=inGeoTensorShape, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, name="Geo" )
print ("In Geo layer shape: %s" % (inGeo.shape,)) # In Geo layer shape: (10, 504)

dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512)(inGeo)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512)(dense1)
dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512)(dense2)
geoOut = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(dense3)

print ("Geo Out Shape: %s" % (geoOut.shape, )) # Geo Out Shape: (10, 512)

# SDF CNN Net
initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0.0, 1.0)

inSDF = tf.keras.Input(shape=inSDFTensorShape, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, name="SDF")
print ("In SDF Shape: %s" % (inSDF.shape,) )  # In SDF Shape: (10, 64, 64, 64, 1)
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(32, 4, padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer, input_shape=inSDFTensorShape)(inSDF) # 32
max1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2))(conv1)
... Many CNN layers ...
conv6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(512, 4, padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer)(max5) # 1
max6 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2))(conv6)
sdfOut = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(max6)

print ("SDF Out Shape: %s" % (sdfOut.shape, )) # SDF Out Shape: (10, 512)

# Concatenation and Output

concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([geoOut, sdfOut])
decode1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512)(concat)
decode2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(decode1)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12)(decode2)

print ("Creating Model")
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inGeo, inSDF], outputs=output ) 
model.summary()

optimiser = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
#loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE()

print("Compiling Model")
model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Training Model")
#model.fit(data_gener#ator(train, test) , epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=30 )
model.fit(dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=10 )
```

Here's the model summary:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
SDF (InputLayer)                [(10, 64, 64, 64, 1) 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d (Conv3D)                 (10, 64, 64, 64, 32) 2080        SDF[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d (MaxPooling3D)    (10, 32, 32, 32, 32) 0           conv3d[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)               (10, 32, 32, 32, 128 262272      max_pooling3d[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3D)  (10, 16, 16, 16, 128 0           conv3d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)               (10, 16, 16, 16, 256 2097408     max_pooling3d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_2 (MaxPooling3D)  (10, 8, 8, 8, 256)   0           conv3d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)               (10, 8, 8, 8, 512)   8389120     max_pooling3d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_3 (MaxPooling3D)  (10, 4, 4, 4, 512)   0           conv3d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Geo (InputLayer)                [(10, 504)]          0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)               (10, 4, 4, 4, 512)   16777728    max_pooling3d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (10, 512)            258560      Geo[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_4 (MaxPooling3D)  (10, 2, 2, 2, 512)   0           conv3d_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (10, 512)            262656      dense[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_5 (Conv3D)               (10, 2, 2, 2, 512)   16777728    max_pooling3d_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (10, 512)            262656      dense_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_5 (MaxPooling3D)  (10, 1, 1, 1, 512)   0           conv3d_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (10, 512)            0           dense_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (10, 512)            0           max_pooling3d_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (10, 1024)           0           flatten[0][0]
                                                                 flatten_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (10, 512)            524800      concatenate[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (10, 128)            65664       dense_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (10, 12)             1548        dense_4[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 45,682,220
Trainable params: 45,682,220
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

And here is the full'ish error (not including the full stack trace):

```
ValueError: in converted code:

    C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py:677 map_fn
        batch_size=None)
    C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py:2410 _standardize_tensors
        exception_prefix='input')
    C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py:582 standardize_input_data
        str(data_shape))

    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected Geo to have shape (504,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

So finally, if someone could point me to where I'm going wrong that would be appreciated. If they could also help me understand why I am getting this error I would be eternally grateful. Understanding shapes in NNs and TF has baffled me so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can provide a more minimal working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that I was using Dataset incorrectly.

After creating my dataset I needed to call batch(BATCH_SIZE) on it, supplying the batch size as an argument.

As TF's dataset doesn't infer the batch size from the input layers but demands the dataset to yield the batches correctly.

Comment: Good job in resolving the issue; you should now accept your own answer (nothing wrong with that).

Answer (score 0):

The `Geo layer` is expecting an input of size `(504,)` but you are giving it an input of size `(1,)`

Maybe when you're doing `norm = norm.flatten()` in `data_generator` it is transforming into an array of size 1 with 504 elements in it. So maybe try to reshape that to `(504,)`